When to use ～に for time? （暑い日、ドラマを見る）
I have two examples where I'm not sure about the particle for time.

私は暑い日、家族と家でビールを飲みます。

Is it necessary to use 「に」after 暑い日？If I don't add a particle would
it be grammatically incorrect?

アンナさんは毎日午後8時に家で母とドラマを見ます。

Someone told me the correct particle after 8時 would be から and not に。Isn't it correct to use both?

Since 暑い日 is a noun phrase, it is followed by some particle (に in this case) in principle. Sometimes, especially in spoken language, particles are omitted, but as a native speaker personally I don’t think it is likely in this particular case.
In the second sentence, に and から are both grammatically possible options, but the choice slightly affects the meaning of the entire sentence. “午後8時にドラマを見る” simply refers to a certain unspecified length of time around 8 pm, but “午後8時からドラマを見る” focuses on that 8 pm is a beginning of their watching.

Thanks for the detailed answer!
